# React query infinite scroll window focus fetch

Tags: next.js, react-query, tanstackreact-query

I have a Next js app with Tanstack query v5.
The server component page makes the prefetchInfiniteQuery and the client component ItemsListInfinite makes the client side fetching.

The problem with this code is that the items show on the screen only after changing the browser tab and returning to it (and you have to wait a few dozen seconds before doing this operation otherwise you won't see anything).

**Query**

```
export function useGetItemsInfinite() {
    const queryFn = async (): Promise<Item[]> => {
        const { data, error } = await getItemsInfinite({ pageParam: 1 });
        if (error) {
            throw error;
        }
        return data || [];
    };

    return queryFn;
}
```

**page.tsx**

```
export default async function ItemsInfinite() {
    const getItemsInfinite = useGetItemsInfinite()
    await queryClient.prefetchInfiniteQuery(
        {
            queryKey: [CACHE_KEY_ITEMS],
            queryFn: getItemsInfinite,
            initialPageParam: 1,
        }
    );

    const queryState = queryClient.getQueryState<InfiniteData<Item[]>>([CACHE_KEY_ITEMS]);
    let prefetchedData: any[] = [];
    if (queryState?.data) {
        prefetchedData = queryState.data.pages.flat();
    }

    console.log("prefetchedData", JSON.stringify(prefetchedData))


    return (
        <HydrationBoundary state={dehydrate(queryClient)}>
            {prefetchedData && <ItemsListInfinite />}
        </HydrationBoundary>
    );
}
```

prefetchedData log:

`[{"id":"xxx","name":"aaa"},..]`

**ItemsListInfinite** (client component list)

```
"use client";
export default function ItemsListInfinite() {
    const {
        data,
        fetchNextPage,
        hasNextPage,
        isFetchingNextPage,
        status,
    } = useInfiniteQuery({
        queryKey: ["items"],
        queryFn: ({ pageParam = 1 }) => {
            return getItemsInfinite({ pageParam });
        },
        initialPageParam: 1,
        getNextPageParam: (lastPage) => (lastPage.currentPage ?? 1) + 1,
    });

    //scroll stuff..

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("data", JSON.stringify(data))
    }, [data])

    return (
        <div
            onScroll={handleScroll}
            ref={scrollContainerRef}
        >
            {status === "pending" ? (
                "Loading..."
            ) : status === "error" ? (
                "Error fetching data."
            ) : (
                <>
                    {data?.pages.map((page, i) => (
                        <Fragment key={i}>
                            {page.data?.map((item: Item, index) => (
                                <div
                                    key={item.id || index}
                                >
                                    <h3>{item.name}</h3>
                                </div>
                            ))}
                        </Fragment>
                    ))}
                    {isFetchingNextPage && <div>Loading...</div>}
                </>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}
```

data log:

`{"pages":[[{"id":"xxx","name":"aaa"},..]],"pageParams":[1]}`